# DynamoDB - Create primary key and attribute if doesn't exist otherwise get

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I'm using DynamoDB where I want to create a primary key and an attribute only if the primary key doesn't exist.

If the primary key exists, I return the primary key and the attribute.

So far I've gotten it to upsert if the primary key doesn't exist, but the issue I'm running into, is that it's still updating the attribute `connectionString` even when the primary key `alexaDeviceId` already exists:

```
const str = randomize('Aa0', 6);

  const params = {
    TableName: "alexa-connections-table",
    Key: {
      "alexaDeviceId": {
        S: process.env.TEST_ALEXA_DEVICE_ID
      }
    },
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
      "#CS": "connectionString"
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ":connection": {
        S: str
      }
    },
    ReturnValues: "ALL_NEW",
    UpdateExpression: "SET #CS = :connection"
  };
  

  try {
    var result = await dynamodb.updateItem(params).promise();
    console.log('Results: ' + JSON.stringify(result));

    return res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(result));
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return res.status(500).send({ reason: err });
  }
```

So for instance when I first run the lambda function with an empty dynamoDB table:

it should add primary key `alexaDeviceId` and 6 digit attribute (working as intended)

```
Column alexaDeviceId: AHJYGV...
Column connectionString: 5Dz2SD
```

when I run the program again

it should NOT do any updates and return

`{"Attributes":{"connectionString":{"S":"5Dz2SD"},"alexaDeviceId":{"S":"AHJYGV..."}}`

instead it's updating the `connectionString` and returning a new value (unexpected result)

`{"Attributes":{"connectionString":{"S":"DxBVmH"},"alexaDeviceId":{"S":"AHJYGV..."}}`

How do I add a condition to not update the `connectionString` if the `alexaDeviceId` primary key already exists?

**Edit:___________________________________________________________________**

I've tried using a `putItem` instead but I can't figure out the correct syntax:

```
const str = randomize('Aa0', 6);

  const params = {
    TableName: "alexa-connections-table",
    Item: {
      "alexaDeviceId": {
        S: process.env.TEST_ALEXA_DEVICE_ID
      },
      "connectionString": {
        S: str
      }
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ':ADI': {'S': process.env.TEST_ALEXA_DEVICE_ID}
    },
    ConditionExpression: 'if_not_exists(alexaDeviceId, :ADI)'
  };
  

  try {
    var result = await dynamodb.putItem(params).promise();
    console.log('Results: ' + JSON.stringify(result));

    return res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(result));
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return res.status(500).send({ reason: err });
  }
```

Giving me the error:

`ValidationException: Invalid ConditionExpression: The function is not allowed in a condition expression; function: if_not_exists`

Answer (score 0):

I used `.putItem()` instead of `.updateItem()` and the ConditionExpression:

`ConditionExpression: 'attribute_not_exists(#ADI)'`

```
const str = randomize('Aa0', 6);

const params = {
    TableName: "alexa-connections-table",
    Item: {
      "alexaDeviceId": {
        S: process.env.TEST_ALEXA_DEVICE_ID
      },
      "connectionString": {
        S: str
      }
    },
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
      "#ADI": "alexaDeviceId"
    },
    ConditionExpression: 'attribute_not_exists(#ADI)'
  };
  

  try {
    var result = await dynamodb.putItem(params).promise();
    console.log('Results: ' + JSON.stringify(result));

    return res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(result));
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return res.status(500).send({ reason: err });
  }
```

This creates a new Item with the attribute `connectionString` if the primary key  does not exist in that table.

`console.log('Results: ' + JSON.stringify(result));`

returns a `ConditionalCheckFailedException`

`ConditionalCheckFailedException: The conditional request failed` if a specific primary key already exists.

It returns `{}` if one does not exist (meaning the `.putItem()` was successful).

Comment: Try with ReturnValues: "ALL_OLD" . PutItem may return items just before they were updated or none at all. Ref : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39451505/how-to-return-the-inserted-item-in-dynamodb

Answer (score -1):

Query DB for specific attribute before doing update.

Ref : [Query dynamodb for a specific field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48365133/query-dynamodb-for-a-specific-field)

Comment: I think there's a way to do it without performing two queries

Comment: Step 3.5: Update an Item (Conditionally)
The following program shows how to use UpdateItem with a condition. If the condition evaluates to true, the update succeeds; otherwise, the update is not performed.

Ref : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.NodeJs.03.html#GettingStarted.NodeJs.03.05

Comment: 1) Query Indicates that item doesn't exist; 2) Someone else adds item; 3) you overwrite it, because (1) said that item doesn't exist.

Comment: Try with ReturnValues: "ALL_OLD" . PutItem may return items just before they were updated or none at all. Ref : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39451505/how-to-return-the-inserted-item-in-dynamodb