# Cannot access Amazon DynamoDB

Tags: node.js, typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

everyone. I'm here to ask a help with Amazon DynamoDB configuration in Node.js + Typescript backend.
I'm trying to create a record to the dynamoDB database.
I'm using Node.js + Express for the backend and faced this error when I try to access DynamoDB

```
Error: Resolved credential object is not valid
    at SignatureV4.validateResolvedCredentials (D:\morgan (2)\React + Node.js\DWQ\server\node_modules\.pnpm\@smithy+signature-v4@2.0.15\node_modules\@smithy\signature-v4\dist-cjs\SignatureV4.js:182:19)   
    at SignatureV4.signRequest (D:\morgan (2)\React + Node.js\DWQ\server\node_modules\.pnpm\@smithy+signature-v4@2.0.15\node_modules\@smithy\signature-v4\dist-cjs\SignatureV4.js:107:14) {
  '$metadata': { attempts: 1, totalRetryDelay: 0 }
}
```

Here is my code.

```
// dbconfig.ts

import { DynamoDBClient } from "@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb";

// Create Amazon DynamoDB service client object
const ddbClient: DynamoDBClient = new DynamoDBClient({
  region: process.env.REGION,
  credentials: {
    accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID!,
    secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY!,
  },
});

export { ddbClient };
```

```
// ddbDocClient.ts

import { DynamoDBDocumentClient } from "@aws-sdk/lib-dynamodb";
import { ddbClient } from "./dbconfig";

const marshallOptions = {
  convertEmptyValues: false, // Whether to automatically convert empty strings, blobs, and sets to `null`
  removeUndefinedValues: true, // Whether to remove undefined values while marshalling
  convertClassInstanceToMap: false, // Whether to convert typeof object to map attribute.
};

const unmarshallOptions = {
  wrapNumbers: false, // Whether to return numbers as a string instead of converting them to native JavaScript numbers.
};

// Create the DynamoDB document client.
const ddbDocClient = DynamoDBDocumentClient.from(ddbClient, {
  marshallOptions,
  unmarshallOptions,
});

export { ddbDocClient };
```

```
// UserController.ts

static async register(req: Request, res: Response) {
    const parsedData: RegisterUserInput = RegisterUserSchema.parse(req.body);
    const { confirm, creditNumber, expireMonth, expireYear, creditCode, creditZip, creditOwner, ...filteredInput } = parsedData;
    const hashedPassword: string = await bcrypt.hash(filteredInput.password, 12);

    // Query command finds user by email
    const queryParams: QueryCommandInput = {
        TableName: "users",
        KeyConditionExpression: "email = :email",
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
            ":email": filteredInput.email,
        },
    };

    // Create a new user data
    const putParams: PutCommandInput = {
        TableName: "users",
        Item: {
            _id: uuidv4(),
            ...filteredInput,
            password: hashedPassword
        }
    };

    await ddbDocClient.send(new QueryCommand(queryParams))
        .then(existUser => {
            // If the user email exists in the database
            if (existUser.Items && existUser.Items.length > 0) {
                res.status(200).json({
                    success: false,
                    message: "User email already exists.",
                });
            } else {
                // Create a new user if it doesn't exist
                // const data = await ddbDocClient.send(new PutCommand(putParams));

                res.status(201).json({
                    success: true,
                    message: "Successfully registered!",
                    result: data,
                });
             }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);

            // Return error response from the server
            res.status(500).json({
                success: false,
                message: "Internal Server Error",
                error
            });
        });
}
```

I can be sure that I have set env variables correctly.
Please help me with that.

Comment: That's not the correct way to test if an item for a given email address exists and write one if it doesn't exist. Instead, use a conditional PutItem (conditional on the absence of the email address key).

Comment: Then how do I catch and log the console if the email does not exist?

Comment: You attempt to [put the item, and catch the failure if it already exists](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69248305), otherwise you're introducing a race condition.

Comment: Your code is not attempting to log to the console if the email does not exist. Your code returns an error it the email address does exist and creates an item if it doesn't exist. You can use conditional PutItem for exactly this and avoid the race condition. See the note at [PutItem](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_PutItem.html).

Answer (score 2):

I would first strongly advise you from coding credentials directly into a client, you should resolve them from role ideally.

However, the exception you are seeing is because you are passing the wrong values as your credentials. My suggestion is to check the values of
`process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID!` & `process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY!`

Answer (score -1):

I solved it by myself. It was because I received empty env variables. I set dotenv config and got them successfully.

```
import { DynamoDBClient } from "@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb";
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';

dotenv.config();

// Create Amazon DynamoDB service client object
const ddbClient: DynamoDBClient = new DynamoDBClient({
  region: process.env.REGION,
  credentials: {
    accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID!,
    secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY!,
  },
});

export { ddbClient };
```

Comment: By yourself, seems like the exact advice I provided you in my answer....